# Swing changes not refelecting in the server

Tags: java, swing

I am using Java Swing. I have done some changes in client pages and I am compiling the entire application, building the ear file and deploying it in Weblogic 8.1 server. But the changes I have done are not reflected in the application. I have restarted the server, deleted logs and cache. Still i am not able to see changes. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using Swing in an applet? Swing applications isn't deployed with ear files as what I know.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is a library that allows creating UI in java. Weblogic is a J2EE application server. EAR file contains your server side application. What is the relationship between updating your server side and changes you are expecting to see on UI?

If you are using java web start or applet check the codebase, i.e. where the **client side** application is started / downloaded from

Comment: Thanks for reply AlexR, iam sorry iam using applet only here iam giving my codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3.1/jinstall-131-win32.cab#Version=1,3,1,0"

Comment: In this case your applet is downloaded from sun's site. I believe you cannot change it unless your are Oracle's sysadmin. :)

Comment: Thanks alot AlexR, Sorry for more questions iam new to Applets. After getting oracle sysadmin rights from sun's site how it will works. can u give a brief on it please.